# BOSUN : How to get Tag_values for a specific Tag_key from BOSUN?

Tags: opentsdb, bosun, scollector

I have a **BOSUN** server running which is configured to operate on **OPENTSDB**. I am sending data to **OPENTSDB** using **SCOLLECTOR** every minute. What I am looking for is a way to get all possible **Tag_Values** for a given **Tag_Key** and **Metric_Name** which is present in **OPENTSDB**.

For Example Suppose I have,

```
metric: data.queue.capacity
tags: queue={queue1,queue2,queue3...}
```

I am storing capacity for a Number of Queues.This data is there in **OPENTSDB**.
I can query BOSUN for values of **metric=data.queue.capacity** using query:

```
q("sum:data.queue.capacity{queue=*}{}","start_time","end_time")
```

which gives output:

```
{queue:queue1} :{"timestamp1":"value1","timestamp2":"value2",...}
{queue:queue2} :{"timestamp1":"value1","timestamp2":"value2",...}
.
.
.
```

The result returned is grouped by different Queue values.
It is hard to use above response data to get all possible Queue names because:

1. It only returns data between start time and end time, So if a Queue name say 
   queue_not does not have a metric point between start_time and end_time, it will not 
   come in the response.
2. This gives a lot of data in response, I can aggregate but I don't think this 
   is the best way to get Tag values.

What I want is an API where I can give a **Metric_Name** and **Tag_Key** and i should get a JSON data having all possible **Tag_Values** present in **OPENTSDB** for that **Metric_Name**,**Tag_Key**.

---

After Searching I have found partial solutions:
**BOSUN** have API to get all **Tag_values**, But for only those metrics which are relayed through BOSUN.

***API: /api/tagv/{tagk}/{metric}***

This API accept's **Tag_key** and **Metric_Name** and for this combination gives all values of **Tag_Values**.

```
eg: http://bosun-host:port/api/tagv/{tagk}/{metric}
response:
[
  "tag_value1",
  "tag_value2"
]
```

Still I don't have a solution to get **Tag_values** for metric which are not relayed through **BOSUN** but directly to **OPENTSDB**.
The solution may not involve **BOSUN** it could be **OPENTSDB** API too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Bosun as concerned, relaying the datapoints to Bosun for that tag metadata is the standard way. You can use [tsdbrelay](https://godoc.org/bosun.org/cmd/tsdbrelay) so metrics get copied to Bosun but don't flow through Bosun (this way if Bosun is restarted or is down, metric flow is not interrupted).

With OpenTSDB itself you could look [into OpenTSDB Metadata](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/metadata.html) - but Bosun't doesn't use this feature of OpenTSDB.